# Persistent selections in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

In [Example 9](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html), if you execute

```
grid.setSelectedRows([0, 1]);
```

the first two rows are effectively selected. But said selection disappears when clicking a row or traversing them with the arrow keys.

Note that `active` (related to the clicks/keydowns) and `selected` (related to the selection model) are two different CSS classes.

How to prevent the mouse and keyboard actions from interacting with the selection model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the active cell tracking affecting the selection, you can set the "selectActiveRow" option in the RowSelectionModel to false.

Comment: oh God, don't know how could I not spot it myself - I literally looked once or twice to the `var _defaults = {selectActiveRow: true};` line. Thank you.